# I am trying to find the nth binary palindrome

Tags: python, algorithm, binary, palindrome

[Binary palindromes: numbers whose binary expansion is palindromic.](https://oeis.org/A006995) 
Binary Palindrome -> is a number whose binary representation is a palindrome. 
[Here is link to the solution with naive approach](http://ideone.com/CfQZuH)

I have read from above link and it give a formula to find the nth binary palindrome. I am unable to understand and thus code the solution.

```
def palgenbase2(): # generator of palindromes in base 2
    #yield 0
    x, n, n2 = 1, 1, 2
    m = 1;
    while True:
        for y in range(n, n2):
            s = format(y, 'b')
            yield int(s+s[-2::-1], 2)
        for y in range(n, n2):
            s = format(y, 'b')
            yield int(s+s[::-1], 2)
        x += 1
        n *= 2
        n2 *= 2
        if n2 > 1000000000:
            break

ans = {}

for i,j in  enumerate(palgenbase2()):
    print i,j
    ans[i]=j

with open("output","a") as f:
    f.write(ans)

#use the saved output to give answer to query later
#this will work but it takes too much time.

n = int(raw_input())
for c in range(0,n):
    z = int(raw_input())
    print ans[z]
```

Here is one Python code but it is generating all such palindromes.
I need help in the program to get the nth binary palindrome directly.
as follows:

> Input -> 1 <= n <= 1000000000
>   Function -> f(n)
>   output -> nth binary palindrome.

Can we do this in better time using the formula mentioned [here](https://oeis.org/A006995)?

Comment: Please include your attempted solutions, and why they didn’t work. Please see the Stack Overflow question checklist for more details.

Comment: @jadsq I think I mentioned that I couldn't code, cuz I am not able to understand what they are saying there. Moreover I have tried almost all the links here on stackoverflow and none of them works for me.

Comment: I have tried in java with some naive approach but its not good enough, if you need I can give that solution.

Comment: Do you understand any python at all ?

Comment: @jadsq Any particular reason for the downvote ?

Comment: @jadsq yes I understand

Comment: The downvote is for the following reason : Your question does not show any trace of attemps to solve the problem by yourself and/or understand the code. You just provided some copy/pasted code and expect someone to do the rest of the work for you. I would be glad to help if you could pinpoint what exactly you don't understand in the provided code.

Comment: @jadsq I did provided the Oeis link, anyways [This is link to my solution](http://ideone.com/CfQZuH). I did tried.

Comment: You are supposed to put the code of your attempted solution in the question itself, not as a link to an external site. However, that code in your ideone link is Java, not Python, and it simply does a brute-force search for palindromes, and it's far less efficient than the generator code from OEIS that you posted.

Comment: The pseudocode of the recursive formula on OEIS is a bit long-winded, but it's really not that hard to implement it in Python. If you can't understand it you need to do what jadsq suggested: pinpoint exactly what you don't understand in the provided pseudocode.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for your guidance. I recently got active on stackoverflow hence I don't understand all the platform's requirements.         I understand the approach is brute-force and hence I am trying to find the better approach. the code they have provided I have been trying to understand, why it works? If possible can you please give me some insights ?

Comment: @PM2Ring I want to implement that recursive formula in python. I am not able to do that.

Comment: **s = True if bin(number)[2:] == bin(number)[2:][::-1] else False** Print `s` for result

Comment: But @PM2Ring point is important. So focus learning not doing something.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried to analyse how that formula works. But I just tested it, and it produces the same results as the generator. And you still haven't explained what's preventing you from implementing that recursive formula in Python. But I guess if I post my implementation you might get a few ideas. :)

Comment: @dsgdfg: Sure, that lets you test if `number` is a binary palindrome. But lordzuko wants a function, eg `bin_palindrome(n)` that returns the nth binary palindrome without doing a brute force search for all previous binary palindromes.

Comment: @PM2Ring This only thing preventing me is the cryptic way those formulae has been written on OEIS website. It's actually confusing me that operator they are trying to use where( specially power, zor, and division).           Your implementation will be very helpful. And will give the answer to this question for others too.

Comment: Sure, OEIS _can be a bit cryptic. Eg, I don't know Maple, so that Maple code is useless to me. :) However, the pseudocode isn't too bad, IMHO. You just need the section starting at `Recursion for n>2: a(n)=2^(2k-q)+1+2^p*a(m)`. But anyway, hopefully my answer makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: build them rather than check if a number is palindrome!

Comment: @jurhas: That's not very efficient if you want, say `binpal(1000000000)`, but the code I posted can do that in under 0.12 seconds on my old 2GHz machine.

Comment: @jurhas What approach are you using for building Nth binary palindrome. Please post an answer, it will definitely help a lot of people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fairly straight-forward implementation of the recursive algorithm given at [A006995](https://oeis.org/A006995).

To make it more efficient I use bit shifting to perform binary exponentiation: when `x` is a non-negative integer, `1 << x` is equivalent to `2 ** x` but substantially faster (at least, it is in both Python 2 and Python 3 on standard CPython).

Also, to make the recursion more efficient, the function stores previously calculated values in a dictionary. This also lets us easily handle when `n <= 2`, which the recursive formula itself does not handle.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Binary palindromes

    Find (non-negative) integers which are palindromes when written in binary

    See http://stackoverflow.com/q/39675412/4014959
    and https://oeis.org/A006995

    Written by PM 2Ring 2016.09.24

    Recursion for n>2: a(n)=2^(2k-q)+1+2^p*a(m), where k:=floor(log_2(n-1)), and p, q and m are determined as follows:

    Case 1: If n=2^(k+1), then p=0, q=0, m=1;

    Case 2: If 2^k<n<2^k+2^(k-1), then set i:=n-2^k, p=k-floor(log_2(i))-1, q=2, m=2^floor(log_2(i))+i;

    Case 3: If n=2^k+2^(k-1), then p=0, q=1, m=1;

    Case 4: If 2^k+2^(k-1)<n<2^(k+1), then set j:=n-2^k-2^(k-1), p=k-floor(log_2(j))-1, q=1, m=2*2^floor(log_2(j))+j; 
'''

#Fast Python 3 version of floor(log2(n))
def flog2(n):
    return n.bit_length() - 1

def binpal(n, cache={1:0, 2:1, 3:3}):
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]

    k = flog2(n - 1)
    b = 1 << k
    a, c = b >> 1, b << 1

    if n == c:
        p, q, m = 0, 0, 1
    elif b < n < a + b:
        i = n - b
        logi = flog2(i)
        p, q, m = k - logi - 1, 2, (1 << logi) + i
    elif n == a + b:
        p, q, m = 0, 1, 1
    else:
        #a + b < n < c
        i = n - a - b
        logi = flog2(i)
        p, q, m = k - logi - 1, 1, (2 << logi) + i

    result = (1 << (2*k - q)) + 1 + (1 << p) * binpal(m)
    cache[n] = result
    return result

def palgenbase2(): 
    ''' generator of binary palindromes '''
    yield 0
    x, n, n2 = 1, 1, 2
    while True:
        for y in range(n, n2):
            s = format(y, 'b')
            yield int(s+s[-2::-1], 2)
        for y in range(n, n2):
            s = format(y, 'b')
            yield int(s+s[::-1], 2)
        x += 1
        n *= 2
        n2 *= 2

gen = palgenbase2()

for i in range(1, 30):
    b = next(gen)
    c = binpal(i)
    print('{0:>2}: {1} {1:b} {2}'.format(i, b, c))
```

**output**

```
 1: 0 0 0
 2: 1 1 1
 3: 3 11 3
 4: 5 101 5
 5: 7 111 7
 6: 9 1001 9
 7: 15 1111 15
 8: 17 10001 17
 9: 21 10101 21
10: 27 11011 27
11: 31 11111 31
12: 33 100001 33
13: 45 101101 45
14: 51 110011 51
15: 63 111111 63
16: 65 1000001 65
17: 73 1001001 73
18: 85 1010101 85
19: 93 1011101 93
20: 99 1100011 99
21: 107 1101011 107
22: 119 1110111 119
23: 127 1111111 127
24: 129 10000001 129
25: 153 10011001 153
26: 165 10100101 165
27: 189 10111101 189
28: 195 11000011 195
29: 219 11011011 219
```

If you need to run this on Python 2 you won't be able to use that `flog2` function, since Python 2 integers do not have the `bit_length` method. Here's an alternative version:

```
from math import floor, log

def flog2(n):
    return int(floor(log(n) / log(2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to write the full code.
Let us exam the algorithm

These columns are : bit count , combinations, combinations count

- 1  1        | 1
- 2  11       | 1
- 3 101 111   | 2
- 4 1001 1111 | 2
- 5 10001 10101 11011 11111 |4
- 6 100001 101101 110011 11111 |4

if you follow this series you are going to increase exponentially each two step. Let n be the bit count which bit count has the following amount of combinations: 2<<((n-1)>>1) .
Now I do not know if it is possible to compute it in close form but recursively is very fast since it is exponential :
let n be the count until the n-1 bit and m the current count

```
int i,n=0,m=0;
for (i=1;m<nth;i++)
{
   n=m;
   m+=2<<((i-1)>>1);
}
```

Now you know how many bits are required: i

You build a char array with (i+1)/2 bits as 100...0
You add (nth-n)-1 (-1 because is 0 based) in binary form. And opla! you mirror your token and end.
Example: you need the 12 element
you are going to sum 1+1+2+2+4+4 . So you know your 12th element has 6 bits.
Until 5 bits you have 10 elements. So 12-10=2  2-1=1
Yout bit looks like
100   ( 6 bit /2)
you add 1-> binary 1
100+1=101
Your nth palindrom number has the follow form 101101. It works also with odd bit count. Check for the singularity 1 and 2 bit count